# Ember CLI and Rails: Error proxying to http://localhost:3000

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, http-proxy

I am following [this tutorial](http://emberigniter.com/modern-bridge-ember-and-rails-5-with-json-api/) for Ember CLI and Rails. I am stuck at the point where you are supposed to load the Book model data using the following command in the console:

```
App.store.findAll('book');
```

No data is retrieved and the Ember terminal logs show this error:

```
Error proxying to http://localhost:3000
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:890:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:913:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1061:14)
GET /books - - ms - -
```

However when I visit http://localhost:3000/books (the Rails backend), I get the correct JSON response with all the books. Why is the Ember app not able to retrieve this data and how can I fix it?

Comment: I currently have the Rails backend and the Ember app in 2 separate folders. Could that be part of it? Should I move the Ember app into a subfolder of the Rails root folder?

Comment: Nope. I ran several Ember+Rails apps. See my answer below. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restart the Rails server with:

```
rails s --binding 0.0.0.0
```

then restart the ember server.

Comment: I am no longer using Ember for this project so I can't test this, but this sounds like it would have probably solved my problem so I'll mark it as accepted unless there are any objections.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things you need to watch.

1. Try setting up in your embers config/environment.js for each environment proper URL and settings. More info [here](https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-cli-content-security-policy/blob/master/README.md).

   ```
     ENV.contentSecurityPolicy = {
       'default-src': "'none'",
       'script-src': "'self'",
       'font-src': "'self'",
       'connect-src': "'self' http://localhost:3000",
       'img-src': "'self' data:",
       'style-src': "'self' 'unsafe-inline'",
       'media-src': "'self'"
   };
   ```
2. And you also need to explain Rails app to accept connection outside of the rails app. CORS. Looks for [this gem](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added the content security policy like you suggested and enabled CORS in Rails with allow everything (origins '*', resource '*', ...) but I still get the same error. There is no indication in the Rails logs of any request coming in and/or being blocked.

Comment: Could you post your embers adapter? application.js or book.js if you are overriding anything.